# URL regular expression exluding specifik domain

Tags: regex

I have a regular expression to match URLs:

```
(?:(?:http|ftp):\/\/)?[^\s]+\.[a-z]{2,}[^\s]*
```

Now I want to allow a specific url and variations of it.

Like `www.example.com`, `http://example.com/slash/slah?hello=world`.

In other means, I want my expression to not match these cases. I've been looking into look ahead and look behind, but cant really put them in place.

I thought of maybe making a regular expression to match the exceptions and replace match them with `___match` , then using the original regexp and only match if it doesn't start with `___`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would better be done in two steps, something like:

```
if ($url =~ /(?:(?:http|ftp):\/\/)?[^\s]+\.[a-z]{2,}[^\s]*/ && 
    $url !~ /www.example.com|http:\/\/example.com\/slash\/slah?hello=world/)
{
   ...
}
```

(Not sure what language you're working in, this is perl code)